# Resolving Firewall after Packet Capture

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, firewall, netfilter

I am stuck up a bit while writing a C Program, I am using `lpcap`and sockets for sniffing traffic and currently i am storing it in a text file.
The second thing i want to do is make a firewall to block a specific port. Now, i came across a `netfilter` Library which works at Kernel space. But the problem is most of my code of Sniffing is currently running in User-Space. I compile my code of sniffer using `gcc` as this sniffer is in user-space. Now, After including trying to implement netfilter for firewall on the same code. It doesn't work as it's a kernel space code. 
The firewall code needs a make file to implement.
and the sniffer is compiled using gcc
Now, How can i mitigate this. i.e. combine both of the things into a single program space.

Comment: I think you are looking for `iptables` instead of using `libnetfilter` or `libiptc` as the maintainer of `netfilter` has mentioned the API are not stable [reference](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq-4.html#ss4.5).  However, if you want to use `libiptc` directly, you can read [this tutorial](https://bani.com.br/2012/05/programmatically-managing-iptables-rules-in-c-iptc/)

Comment: I want to code in C rather then using Command of Iptable. Is it possible to code iptable? @SSC

Comment: You can read the [tutorial](https://bani.com.br/2012/05/programmatically-managing-iptables-rules-in-c-iptc/) or just google `libiptc` for more information.

Comment: @SSC libiptc/libiptc.h: No such file or directory that's what i am getting while compiling

Comment: I am not sure what linux distro you are using.  So I don't why you cannot find `libiptc.h`.  In Debian/Ubuntu, it is included in the `iptables-dev` package.  After the package is installed, it is in `/usr/include/libiptc/`.